# Checbox check condition inside gridview not working as required in javascript

Tags: javascript, gridview, checkbox

I have a `GRIDVIEW` in which there are 18 rows, what I want is

> Atleast one checkbox from each row should be checked.

I tried with the below code:-

```
 $(function () {
      $("#CmdSave1").click(function () {
          for (i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {
              if (typeof $(".row-" + i + ":checked").val() == "undefined")
                  $(".row-" + i).closest("tr").addClass("error");
          }
          if ($(".error").length > 0)
              alert("Select the checkbox from each row");
          return false;
      });
  });
```

> with the above code, it is working if I check 3 rows from 18 rows. But when I check all the 18 rows of the gridview, it still giving me the alert message.

Kindly let me know what is going wrong with the code

Below is the Image of the gridview

[![Screenshot][1]][1]

Added the code in fiddle below

**https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0ooot2/**

Comment: @RayonDabre: like this `if (typeof $(".row-" + i + ":checked")) == "undefined")` ??

Comment: @RayonDabre: No its not working. The form is submitted without any row checked

Comment: @RayonDabre: cant execute but provided the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1j5e0yu4/2/

Comment: @RayonDabre: also have a look at here http://jsbin.com/jebecapopu/edit?html,output

Comment: @RayonDabre: any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: @Satindersingh: how to do that in server side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `tr` selector and find all the radio elements using `:radio` selector. Filter them out using `.filter`.

If length of checked radio elements is `0`, add `error` class or remove

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    $('tr').each(function() {
      var len = $(this).find(':radio').filter(function() {
        return this.checked;
      }).length;
      if (!len) {
        $(this).addClass("error")
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass("error")
      }
    })
  })
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
}
tr.error td {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Row 1</th>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-1" class="row-1" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-1" class="row-1" value="2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-1" class="row-1" value="3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-1" class="row-1" value="4">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Row 2</th>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-2" class="row-2" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-2" class="row-2" value="2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-2" class="row-2" value="3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-2" class="row-2" value="4">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Row 3</th>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-3" class="row-3" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-3" class="row-3" value="2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-3" class="row-3" value="3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-3" class="row-3" value="4">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Row 4</th>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-4" class="row-4" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-4" class="row-4" value="2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-4" class="row-4" value="3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-4" class="row-4" value="4">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Row 5</th>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-5" class="row-5" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-5" class="row-5" value="2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-5" class="row-5" value="3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-5" class="row-5" value="4">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Row 6</th>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-6" class="row-6" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-6" class="row-6" value="2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-6" class="row-6" value="3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-6" class="row-6" value="4">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Row 7</th>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-7" class="row-7" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-7" class="row-7" value="2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-7" class="row-7" value="3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-7" class="row-7" value="4">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Row 8</th>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-8" class="row-8" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-8" class="row-8" value="2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-8" class="row-8" value="3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-8" class="row-8" value="4">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Row 9</th>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-9" class="row-9" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-9" class="row-9" value="2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-9" class="row-9" value="3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-9" class="row-9" value="4">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Row 10</th>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-10" class="row-10" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-10" class="row-10" value="2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-10" class="row-10" value="3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="row-10" class="row-10" value="4">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Click" class="btn">
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/t5nf0xq4/)

Comment: i am able to select only one radio button from whole grid, see the fiddle..https://jsfiddle.net/jdhjzrpL/

Comment: I am not familiar with the template engine you are using..It is not even being parsed in fiddle you have provided..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105638/discussion-between-coder-and-rayon-dabre).

Comment: hi bro, are you their ??